# How to optimize COUNTIFS with very large data

Tags: excel, optimization, excel-formula, large-data

I would like to create a report that look like this picture below. 
My data has around 500,000 cells (it will continue to grow larger) 
 
Right now, I'm using countifs function from excel but it takes a very long time to calculate. (cannot turnoff automatic calculate) 
 
The main value is collected as date and the range of date is about 3 years, so I have to put a lot of formula to cover all range of value.

[image: result][result](https://fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t1.0-9/988459_701467203302504_2667600209275229377_n.jpg?oh=28850ac03b23d2bfbc1afede19d96ec2&oe=556E57E9&__gda__=1428451333_4ab6f68baae6b87bb46d8e75041c07ce)


The picture below is the datasource the top one cannot be changed. , while the bottom is the one I created by myself (can change). I use weeknum to change date to week number.

[image: data][data](https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/1012966_701467206635837_6234293700065069575_n.jpg?oh=bc5c9ea5765c1d36ea7f4251ac3b7db0&oe=556C36A9&__gda__=1432896050_ee7f07409a22e380d1dfcd2b769785cc)

 
Are there any better formula or any ways to make this file faster? Every kinds of suggestions are welcome! 
I was thinking about using Pivot Table, but I don't know how to make pivot table from this kind of datasource. 
PS. VBA is the last option.

You can download example file here: https://www.mediafire.com/?t21s8ngn9mlme2d

Comment: What is a "very long time"?

Comment: I mean the calculation time. Since I have to create 2 levels formula (1 to convert date to weeknum, another is to count weeknum with conditions)

Comment: I meant how long does it actually take

Comment: Oh...it's about 5-10 minutes depends on computer. But it's very annoying because every time  I filer data, the calculation starts. And I cannot disable auto calculate function because it'll ruin other parts of document. So, I want to reduce formula or use other formula or use pivot table to improve its performance.

Comment: @Krsnik195 What about disabling autocalculation just for the time when you are entering new data; then re-enable after?

Comment: In addition to @Ron Rosenfeld's advice, I would ask if this has to be an excel file. If it's just going to get bigger, these problems will only get worse every time a calculation is needed. Have you considered putting this into an Access database?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld : This file will be used for many people. Someone just want to open and see what's it inside while other may have to input data. So, the levels of excel skill of each people are different. Turning off auto calculation is something I've been trying to avoid.

Comment: @nwhaught : For now it has to be Excel file. But in the future maybe we'll try to consider putting it to access database. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: @Krsnik195 Perhaps you could automate things better, either with a button with an understandable label, or with an event macro that disables autocalc if a selection is made in the data entry area.  Otherwise, I doubt that Excel will be the best tool for this database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will post this answer with the disclaimer that it is entirely dependent on the size of the data set.  That turning on and off the auto calculate is the best way, but your question doesn't let me do that, so keep reading.

Your question made me curious, so I gave it a try and timed it.  I essentially set up two columns of over 100,000 rand numbers choosing from 1-1000 and then tried to do a countif on the two columns if they were equal.  I made a macro that I can run that turns off the autocalculate, inserts the start time, calculates, and then inserts the finish time.  I highlighted in yellow the time difference.

First I tried your way, two criteria, countifs: [image]

Then I tried to combine (concatenate) the two columns to see if I could make it easier by only having one countif criteria and data set.  It doesn't. see result below:[image]

Finally, realizing what was going on.  I decided to make the criteria only match the FIRST value in the number to look for.  I was essentially reducing the number of characters to check per cell.  This had a positive result.  See below: [image]

Therefore my suggestion is to limit the length of the words you are comparing in anyway possible.  You are mostly looking at dates, so you might have to get creative, but this seems to be the best way possible without going to manual calculation.

Comment: Your suggestion is very interesting. I'll try to adapt with my data :)

Answer (score 1):

I have worked with Excel sheets of a similar size. Especially if you are using the data on a regular basis, I would heartily recommend switching to a proper database SQL based, Access, or whatever fits your purpose. I does wonders for the speed and also you won't run into the size limits of Excel. :-)

You can import the data you have now fairly easy.
I am happy as a clam with my postgresql db.